# How to set camera position in scenekit

Tags: 3d, camera, scenekit

I have a moving man and a 3d map and i want this character should move under this map but the character always move outside the map.I want the character should move inside the map as consider in a room but it is not in right place.Can somebody help me how to set camera position so that map and moving character both should be visible and character should move inside the map? Here is my code

```
 // create a new scene
    scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Messi.dae")!

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 0.01
    cameraNode.camera?.zFar = Double(max(map.width, map.height))
    stillCamera(self)

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
```

Here i create a child node of my moving character and fix its position according to the map entity with SCNPhysicsShape

```
messiArmtr = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Armtr", recursively: true)!

    mountNode.addChildNode(messiArmtr)
    for entity in map.entities {
        switch entity.type {
        case .Hero:
            mountNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCylinder(radius: 0.2, height: 1), options: nil))
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                mountNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ~0
            }

    mountNode.position = SCNVector3(x: entity.x, y: 0.5, z: entity.y)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(mountNode)

        case .Monster:

            let monsterNode = SCNNode()
            monsterNode.position = SCNVector3(x: entity.x, y: 1, z: entity.y)
            monsterNode.geometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.04, height: 0.01)
            monsterNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: monsterNode.geometry!, options: nil))
        }
    }
```

Now i set moving character to follow camera

```
func followCamera(sender:AnyObject){
    mountNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    cameraNode.constraints = nil
    cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0,1,0,M_PI)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0,10,-15)

}
```

The character movee where the camera goes but outside of the map as you can see in this image[image: map is very low and character is above][image]
How can i set my camera position so that this moving man should move in colored map streets??